# How do I get my questions answered?

Tags: discussion

I've asked a handful of questions here and have not received any help? Is this website dead? Where can I go for help for all the bugs I have?

I'm asking this again, because the moderator thought he should delete it.  If a moderator deletes my question asking where to get help how am I ever going to get help?

Comment: Your questions are from last year and don't have any updates on them; usually abandoned questions tend to go unanswered.

Comment: the community FAQ should help you write better questions with more details to make the question actually answerable - http://askubuntu.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 2):

Honestly? Ask better questions. You have asked 4 questions, let's have a look at them:

- https://askubuntu.com/q/385068/85695

  This one is impossible to answer. You give absolutely no information. Your question boils down to

  > Does anyone know why my computer will sometimes go to sleep after the time I set in powersettings and other times it does not go to sleep?

  Put yourself in our position, how can we know what's wrong with your computer? There are hundreds of possible reasons starting from the simple "you sometimes move the mouse so it doesn't sleep" to the complex "strange bug in the powersettings module".

  Now, *what* powersettings module? How are you setting this? What graphical environment are you using? Or is this a headless setup with no GUI? How have you tested? What did you try etc. You need to give information else the question cannot be answered and will be ignored. This particular one was closed as "too broad" by various users, including myself.
- https://askubuntu.com/q/383048/85695

  "The right click menu *touchy*"? I have no idea what you're talking about. Reading the question itself, you seem to be having some issues with your right click menu on the Desktop. OK, again, what graphical environment are you using? Which version? Which Ubuntu version? How exactly could we reproduce this?

  Oh, by the way, it sounds like a faulty mouse, try with another mouse and see if you get the same issue. Then **edit** your question and add that information.
- [Ethernet works with live CD, but doesn't after fresh install.](https://askubuntu.com/q/375478/85695)

  This one is marginally better since at least you mention the Ubuntu version and that your card is not shown by `ifconfig`. However, it would be greatly improved if you include the actual output from `ifconfig`. Also, you were asked to provide more details:

  > We need additional details. Please edit your question to add details of both network devices from a terminal: lspci -nn -d 14e4: –  chili555 Nov 11 '13 at 16:00

  You did not respond to that. In general, when the OP (original poster) ignores the community's comments and requests for information, the community will ignore the question. Basically, if you can't be bothered to reply and give the information we need to be able to help you, why should we be bothered to try?

  Also, copy pasting the name of your card into Google gave me the question below as a first hit and I am now voting to close your question as a duplicate of this one. Next time, please take the time to search the internet in general and the site in particular before posting:

  [Broadcom BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX Issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/14970/85695)
- https://askubuntu.com/q/346254/85695

  This one is pretty much OK. You have actually told us you are using Unity and the question is clear and easy to understand. It has also been "answered", a duplicate existed on the site and your question has been marked as a copy of it.

So, in conclusion, the reason you have not gotten answers is that in most cases there are serious problems with your questions. Please don't take this personally, the Stack Exchange model takes some getting used to, I recommend you read some or all of these:

- https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
- [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [Stack Overflow legend Jon Skeet on asking questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

In general, if your questions are:

1. Clear;
2. Contain the necessary information;
3. Show that you have at least tried to solve it yourself;
4. Show that you are willing to do some work and don't expect us to do everything for you;

then they will get the attention they deserve.